# Application(mumbai region) gets random timeout from read replica on mumbai : AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, rds

My application is hosted on virginia as well as mumbai EC2 instances and we use geo based location routing for our application . Now our Prod RDS is hosted in Virginia region which has a read replica in Mumbai region.
For all write operations we use Virginia region RDS and for all read actions(for mumbai region users only) we use mumbai region RDS. Now we are receiving random connection timeout errors from RDS . This can be some lag but we have set our timeout to 10000ms. Virginia region users have never reported this issue(their read/write actions point to virginia RDS only).

Any suggestion if we need to modify any setting in RDS?

Comment: You are saying that when trying to establish connections from the application to the RDS replica server, you are getting occasional timeout errors in the application?  Or timeouts when the Mumbai application connects to the Virginia RDS master for writes?  Or something else?  What is the exact error?

Comment: Mumbai server gets random timeouts while reading from mumbai RDS replica.

ERROR is : "db connection is not available: request timeout out after 10000ms."